# Flask SocketIO raises a ValueError

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I am trying to set up a Flask server which can use `SocketIO`, however it doesn't work and it returns me this following error:

```
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

This is my setup for the flask environment:

```
export FLASK_APP=application.py
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

Then I run like I would normally do, and would work before I started using `SocketIO`:

```
flask run
```

Here is my code for `application.py`, which is very simple but maybe it helps:

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello, world"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask APP - ValueError: signal only works in main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53522052/flask-app-valueerror-signal-only-works-in-main-thread)

Comment: I have read that thread, however it didn't help since I am not able to use SocketIO while debug mode is on on my flask server.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem. Maybe you should include details such as python version, version of Flask and version of Flask-SocketIO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current releases of Flask-SocketIO the `flask run` method to start the server can only be used when working with the Flask development server, which is not recommended because it does not support WebSocket.

What I recommend that you do is that you change your application as follows:

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello, world"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

And then run the application with:

```
python application.py
```

Answer (score 2):

I am playing with flask_socketio just to understand how it works. So my workaround might not be ideal.

I ran following the terminal

```
$ export FLASK_ENV=production 
$ flask run
```

I got following warning but my test application worked

```
Serving Flask app "<applicationname>.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
[2019-03-20 09:58:09,131] WARNING in __init__: Flask-SocketIO is Running under Werkzeug, WebSocket is not available.
```