# python How can I run flask app in a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

How can I run my flask app in a separate thread?
I am able to run my flask app in main, but

I need to launch the flask app from a thread, that thread should be running while in main thread I initiate an event for the thread engine to start.

so this works fine

```
@app.route("/voice", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def voice():
  .........
  return str(resp)

@app.route("/mainFlow", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mainFlow():
    """Respond """
    .......

    return str(resp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

but I need something like this

```
def myIVR():
    print("-----------------Thrd1-myIVR --------------------")
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.run(debug=True)

    @app.route("/voice", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def voice():
      ........
      return str(resp)

    @app.route("/mainFlow", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def mainFlow():
        """Respond to """
        resp = VoiceResponse()

def myTest():
    print("E2Etest")
    thrd1 = threading.Thread(target=myIVR, args=[])
    thrd1.start()
    print("trigger event")
    #xyz()

################################################################
def main():
    myTest()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get this error

```
  File "C:\......\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

Comment: did you check this linki https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53522052/flask-app-valueerror-signal-only-works-in-main-thread

Comment: Thank you, it looks like it has been asked about debug, I am wondering about threading. I also do know that I can run Flask in main thread, and I am NOT Using debugging.  I need to run in threading mode.

Comment: Isvthis link answer your question or not ?

Comment: I have a working example you can crib from. https://github.com/davewsmith/lapse/blob/master/lapse.py#L31 is where I launch the thread to run Flask. Note in particular the `use_reloader=False` part, which avoids much sadness.

Comment: it works Dave thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
from flask import Flask                                                         
import threading
app = Flask(__name__)



def myIVR():
  print("-----------------Thrd1-myIVR --------------------")
  app = Flask(__name__)
  threading.Thread(target=app.run).start()

@app.route("/voice", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def voice():
  return str(resp)

@app.route("/mainFlow", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mainFlow():
    """Respond to """
    resp = VoiceResponse()

def myTest():
  print("E2Etest")
  thrd1 = threading.Thread(target=myIVR, args=[])
  thrd1.start()
  print("trigger event")
#xyz()

################################################################
def main():
    myTest()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

or use the flask with debuging mode False it will fix your problem :

```
from flask import Flask                                                         
import threading
app = Flask(__name__)



def myIVR():
  print("-----------------Thrd1-myIVR --------------------")
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.run(debug=False)

@app.route("/voice", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def voice():
  return str(resp)

@app.route("/mainFlow", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mainFlow():
    """Respond to """
    resp = VoiceResponse()

def myTest():
  print("E2Etest")
  thrd1 = threading.Thread(target=myIVR, args=[])
  thrd1.start()
  print("trigger event")
#xyz()

################################################################
def main():
    myTest()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ok so i will delete my answer if it's not helpfull because you dosen't upvoted it or marked it as helpfull